# android emulator - unfortunately "App name", has stopped. in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am trying to create a simple android application in eclipse. The emulator works fine when I tried to run the “Hello world” that is automatically created by eclipse and it works fine. But when I tried to create a simple program and run it, the emulator pop-up “Unfortunately the OddOrEven has stopped”. I also tried to my android phone but they have the same error. What should I do? I am just a beginner trying to learn how to make android application.

*This is my android manifest file:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.IDB.oddoreven"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.IDB.oddoreven.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

*This is my mainactivity file:*

```
    package com.IDB.oddoreven;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
//import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.*;
//import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tbInput);
        final TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tbResult);
        Button check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCheck);

        check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Double num = Double.parseDouble(input.getText().toString());

                num = Double.parseDouble(calc.multiNum(num));

                output.setText(num+"");
            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

*This is my calc.java file:*

```
package com.IDB.oddoreven;

public class calc {

    public static String multiNum(double x){
        String re= "";
        double num = x * 5;

        re = num + "";
        return re;
    }

    }
```

*This is my fragment_main.xml:*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.IDB.oddoreven.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tbInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="12sp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCheck"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tbInput"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tbResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnCheck"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnCheck"
        android:inputType="text" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

*This is my **logcat**:*

```
03-23 13:29:24.383: D/AndroidRuntime(601): Shutting down VM
03-23 13:29:24.393: W/dalvikvm(601): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3aa6d58)
03-23 13:29:24.433: E/AndroidRuntime(601): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-23 13:29:24.433: E/AndroidRuntime(601): Process: com.IDB.oddoreven, PID: 601
03-23 13:29:24.433: E/AndroidRuntime(601): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.IDB.oddoreven/com.IDB.oddoreven.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-23 13:29:24.433: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2208)
03-23 13:29:24.433: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
03-23 13:29:24.433: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
03-23 13:29:24.433: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
03-23 13:29:24.433: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-23 13:29:24.433: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-23 13:29:24.433: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5042)
03-23 13:29:24.433: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 13:29:24.433: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-23 13:29:24.433: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:776)
03-23 13:29:24.433: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
03-23 13:29:24.433: E/And`enter code here`roidRuntime(601):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-23 13:29:24.433: E/AndroidRuntime(601): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-23 13:29:24.433: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at com.IDB.oddoreven.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
03-23 13:29:24.433: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-23 13:29:24.433: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-23 13:29:24.433: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2172)
03-23 13:29:24.433: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: You need to look at MainActivity.java class line 27.

Comment: Which one is your line number 27 ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I see the problem. Your views are on `fragment_main` and your `Activity` inflate `activity_main`, whereas your Fragment `PlaceholderFragment` inflate the right one where your Button and EditTexts are.
You should put this in your Fragment `onCreateView` method as:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    // don't forget, you need the inflated View to find their ids (rootView).
    final EditText input = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tbInput);
    final EditText output = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tbResult);
    Button check = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnCheck);

    check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Double num = Double.parseDouble(input.getText().toString());
            num = Double.parseDouble(calc.multiNum(num));
            output.setText(num+"");
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Let me know if this helps.